# No arbitrage principle in Counterparty Credit Risk

Tags: no-arbitrage-theory, counterparty-risk

I think this is a fairly basic question but I'm struggling to understand the no-arbitrage principle applied to CCR.

Imagine that we want to calculate the exposure evolution in an IR derivative, comparing risk-neutral vs real-world probabilities. We will have two different profiles that have the same value on the day of today due to the no-arbitrage principle.

Why are both valuations equal? Is it because both are considering the current market value of the trade, and as time goes by, the evolution is different depending on the way the drift and volatility parameters are calculated? If it is not due to the current market value, how are the parameters of the pricers adjusted to have the same result?

Many thanks,

Comment: I guess by calculating the exposure evolution you mean to simulate how the expected loss of the IR derivative might change in the future. To simplify the discussion lets focus on the question how the MtM of the IR derivative develops in the future. As far as I know there is no consensus if the market parameters are to be simulated with a risk-neutral or with real-world probability measure. So they might be different on future dates. The reason that they agree today is that we know the MtM and there is nothing left to simulate.